# does google translate api support HTML? if so does it charge for text characters or full text?

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I want to know if google translate can handle html tags, i.e.: can I send this:

```
<p>hello <strong>world</strong></p>
```

and wil it translate it to spanish like this: ?

```
<p>hola <strong>mundo</strong></p>
```

If so, does google charge per character including the html chars or just the text chars?

If not, can you recommend another similar service that does?